# need help regarding skipping a downstream job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to test a Jenkins job A which triggers a downstream job B .

But for my testing purpose i dont want to run B. is there a way i can skip the downstream job(s) for a particular run?

Is there any plugin available for the same ?

I searched and could not find a solution for the same other than temporarily removing/adding downstream jobs.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, couldn't you just use the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to run the downstream job, and simply just remove the reference from the downstream job from the parent job?  Then you aren't removing or adding jobs, just removing or adding a reference to a job.  So, in the `Projects to build` field where it requires a comma delimited list of projects, just add and remove to suit the situation.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply.. I am using Parameterized trigger build now to call the downstream job.. but am not getting how to remove the reference from the donwstream job ? Could you please explain little more ?